# Getting multiple 'driver.find_elements_by_xpath' as .text at once - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, element

Is there a way to get multiple '.get_attribute("text")' at once, it seems to only work with getting multiple element ID's at once.

Works

```
locationAndType = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/li/a/span")
```

Doesn't work

```
locationAndType = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/li/a/span").get_attribute("text")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` return a list. But you can use a list comprehension to unpack the attribute in one expression:

```py
locationAndType = [elem.get_attribute("text") 
                   for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/li/a/span")]
```